# Crop unused margin in a ggplot plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, crop

I have created a ggplot worldmap that I want to save as svg. Both work fine. However, I want to change/specify the area of the plot that gets saved.

My code looks as follows:

```
raw_plot = ggplot(data = world_for_plot,
                  aes(x = long,
                      y = lat,
                      group = group,
                      fill = "black")) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = results)) +
  coord_equal(1.3, expand=F) +
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = '#F6F6F6', guide=F)

ggsave(file = "FOLDER\\LATAM.svg",
       plot = raw_plot)
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]

However, I want to have a file/plot that doesn't have all the unnecessary white space on top and bottom:

[image]

Any ideas? I already figured out that the `coord_equal` command creates some problems. Without it, the plot fills out the whole plot area. However, I need the `coord_equal` command, otherwise the world map would look stretched.

Comment: specify the size and shape of the figure you want in ggsave

Comment: But this just "zooms" the plot in or out, no? E.g. if I specify width = and height = ..., it chnages the ratios of the plot, but it doesn't crop x pixels on top and x pixels at the bottom.

Comment: If you pick the aspect ratio correctly (to match the plot) the extra margin will go away

Comment: Ok, I played around with it and I can indeed reduce the margin. However, I didn't manage to delete it completely and depending on the wdith/height values, the ratio in the plot of course changes. Since I selected a coord_equal value of 1.3, this should be my aspect ratio for height/width, but that still leaves some margin.

Answer (score 1):

This might work if you adjust the lengths:

```
raw_plot + theme(plot.margin = margin(-2, 0, -2, 0, "cm"))
```

The order of the margins here is top, right, bottom, left.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same problem so here're my solutions for people with the same issue.

`tmaptools` has a function [`get_asp_ratio`](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmaptools/blob/master/R/get_asp_ratio.R) to compute the aspect ratio of spatial objects. We can use that ratio to remove the outer margin of any map.

```
library(ggplot2)

world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") # to get the world map

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world) +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_void()

asp <- tmaptools::get_asp_ratio(world) # returns 2.070007

height <- 5
ggsave("world.svg", width = height * asp, height = height)
```

Alternatively, if we don't want to depend on `tmaptools`, we can make our own functions with a wrapper around `ggsave`. This is essentially based on the `tmaptools::get_asp_ratio` function.

```
deg_to_rad <- function(x) {
  (mean(x) * pi) / 180
}

get_aspect_ratio <- function(geometry) {
  if (!inherits(geometry, c("Spatial", "Raster", "sf", "sfc"))) {
    stop('"geometry" must be of class "Spatial", "Raster", "sf" or "sfc".')
  }
  bbox <- sf::st_bbox(geometry)
  xlim <- bbox[c(1, 3)]
  ylim <- bbox[c(2, 4)]
  xdeg <- diff(xlim)
  ydeg <- diff(ylim)
  if (xdeg == 0 || ydeg == 0) {
    asp <- 1
  } else {
    is_lon_lat <- sf::st_is_longlat(geometry)
    asp <- unname((xdeg / ydeg) * ifelse(is_lon_lat, cos(deg_to_rad(ylim)), 1))
  }
  asp
}

save_ggmap <- function(filename, plot = last_plot(), width = NA, height = NA, ...) {
  geometry <- ggplot_build(plot)$data[[1]]$geometry
  asp <- get_aspect_ratio(geometry)
  if (is.na(width) && !is.na(height)) {
    width <- height * asp
  } else if (is.na(height) && !is.na(width)) {
    height <- width / asp
  }
  ggsave(filename, plot, width = width, height = height, ...)
}
```

We can use the function the same way as `ggsave`. We only have to specify either the `width` or `height` and the function will save the map with the right aspect ratio automatically.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world) +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_void()

save_ggmap("world.svg", width = 8)
```

To remove the inner margin, we can use `theme(plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0))`.